# How to overcome SQLite View limitation

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Given that in SQLite, `View`s:

- are read-only
- cannot be `UPDATE`d,

the following is the situation:

There are 4 tables `A`,  `B`, `C` and `D` and a `View` has to be created with data from all the four tables conditionally. Here's the pseudo-construct:

```
CREATE VIEW AS E SELECT A.A1, A.A2, A.A3, A.A4, B.B1, C.C1, C.C2, D.D1, D.D2 FROM A, B, C, D
WHERE A.X = 'SOME STRING' AND
    A.FK = C.PK AND
    A.Y = B.Z AND 
    D.G = A.PK AND
    D.H = 'SOME STRING'
```

The requirement is that, irrespective of no matches in `D`, the remaining matches should get populated, (with 0 values in the view `E` for the columns from `D`). Needless to say, the above construct works if there *are* matching `D` rows, but obviously returns an empty view if there are no `D` matches.

How can the `CASE` statement or `SELECT` sub-queries (or an altogether different construct, like an `INSTEAD OF` trigger) deliver this requirement?

Greatly appreciate if the database experts could publish the ***exact*** construct(s). Many, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using `LEFT JOIN` syntax instead of the implicit joining in the `FROM` clause? Also, please inform us whether you *must have* or *can have* rows matching in A, B, C and D, and what to do in each case. Ie. if a match is missing in B, do you want to still return the row from A, or leave it out?

Comment: Show example data and the desired result. And it *is* possible to make a view updatable with a trigger.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, 
 - Haven't tried `LEFT JOIN`.
 - MUST have rows matching in A, B, C and D. If there are no matches in D,  D1 and D2 in the view should be zero. 

Thanks!

Comment: @CL, Working on a fiddle. Meanwhile, please explain how to update the view with a trigger. Thanks!

Comment: @CL., Please run the [fiddle](http://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-55af71867f282d1e6de8e7e73a3892a4502bce6f3e55c64285) before and after deleting the record from table `Donkey`. Thanks!

Comment: This information belongs into the question. Your question about updating views cannot be answered because you have not stated your actual problem.

Comment: @CL.The problem is that the query above works if the last two AND conditions are removed. But even when there's no match in the last two conditions, the requirement is that the view should be populated as if the conditions never existed, but with zeroes in the non-matching columns. Its a simple requirement IMHO, but the right construct is not striking. 

Could not understand when you say, _information belongs into the question_. A fiddle is in the comment. Kindly let me know if you need even more details. Can share the database and the query _as-is_ too. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @CL.In other words, please assume the `CREATE VIEW` query minus the last two `AND` conditions. The view gets created as required. How can two columns in this new view be updated with the information required from table `D`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use explicit joins:

```
SELECT A.A1, A.A2, A.A3, A.A4, B.B1, C.C1, C.C2, D.D1, D.D2
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.Y = B.Z
JOIN C ON A.FK = C.PK
JOIN D ON D.G = A.PK
WHERE A.X = 'SOME STRING'
  AND D.H = 'SOME STRING';
```

Then you can use an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join) when you want to keep rows without a match:

```
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.Y = B.Z
JOIN C ON A.FK = C.PK
LEFT JOIN D ON D.G = A.PK AND D.H = 'SOME STRING'
WHERE A.X = 'SOME STRING';
```

(The `D.H` comparison must be part of the join condition because `D.H` is NULL for missing rows, and the comparison would fail in the WHERE clause.)

Comment: This answer helped a great deal and the requirement got fulfilled basis this concept. Thank you so much!

Not sure why the question got down-voted. Nevertheless, hope this discussion proves to be useful to SO users. Thanks again, CL and SO!